# Newton's Second Law and Second-order Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following question is from Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol. 1:

> A particle of unit mass moves along the x-axis and is acted upon by a
> force $f(x) = -\sin x$.
>
> (a) Determine the motion of the point if at time $t=0$ it is at the
> point $x=0$ and has velocity $v_0=2$. Show that as $t \to \infty$ the
> particle approaches a limiting position, and find this limiting
> position.
>
> (b) If the conditions are the same, except that $v_0$ may have any
> value, show that if $v_0 > 2$ the point moves to an infinite distance
> as $t \to \infty$, and that if $v_0 < 2$ the point oscillates about
> the origin.

---

Solving part (a) wasn't too difficult using Courant's method of solving second order differential equations that arise from Newton's Second Law:

> Using Newton's Second Law, we can write: $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\sin (x(t)) = \frac{d}{dx}\cos(x(t))$$ Multiplying both sides by
> $\frac{dx}{dt}$, we obtain: $$\begin{align}
> \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt} &=
> [\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x(t))]\frac{dx}{dt} \\
> \frac{d}{dt}[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2] &=\frac{d}{dt}[\cos (x(t))]
> \end{align}$$ Integrating both sides with regards to $t$, we obtain: $$\begin{align}
> \frac{1}{2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 &= \cos (x(t))+c \\ \frac{dx}{dt} &=
> \sqrt{2(\cos (x(t)) + c)} \end{align}$$ Using the given initial
> conditions, we can find the value of the constant: $$\frac{dx}{dt}(0)
> = \sqrt{2(\cos (x(0)) + c)} = \sqrt{2(1 + c)} = 2 \\ \therefore c = 1 $$
>
> Since we cannot find $x$ as a function of $t$ by direct integration,
> we will instead find $t$ as a function of $x$ by integration:
> $$\begin{align} \frac{dt}{dx} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\cos (x(t)) + 1)}}
> \\ \int \frac{dt}{dx} dx &= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\cos (x(t)) + 1)}}
> \\ t(x) &= \sinh^{-1}(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))+c_1 \end{align}$$
> Re-arranging the equation, we obtain: $$x(t)=2\tan^{-1} (\sinh
> (t-c_1))$$  Since $x(0) = 0$, the value of $c_1 = 0$ and $x(t)$
> simplifies to: $$x(t) = 2\tan^{-1} (\sinh t) = 4\tan^{-1} (e^x) -
> \pi$$ Thus, the limiting position of the particle is: $$\lim_{t \to
> \infty} x(t) = \pi$$

The problem I have with part (b) is that the integral I obtain to find $t(x)$ isn't actually computable:

> From part (a), we know the expression for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ to be:
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{2(\cos (x(t)) + c)}$$
> and using the initial conditions, we can find an expression for c:
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} (0) = \sqrt{2(\cos (x(0)) + c)} = v_0 \\ \therefore c = \frac{v_0^2}{2}-1$$
> Now, the expression for $\frac{dt}{dx}$ becomes:
> $$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos (x) + v_0^2 -2}}$$

Since the general expression for $\frac{dt}{dx}$ can't be integrated, I tried to build an argument around the graph/shape of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ and its properties:

> The first thing I noticed was that depending on the value of $v_0$,
> $\frac{dt}{dx}$ may or may not have a vertical tangent.
> $\frac{dt}{dx}$ has a vertical tangent at points where $\sqrt{2\cos x+ v_0^2 -2} = 0$, and these points are: $$\begin{align} 2\cos x + v_0^2 -2 &= 0 \\ x &= \cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}) \end{align}$$
> from which it is clear that $\frac{dt}{dx}$ has vertical tangents when
> $v_0 \leq 2$ and does not have vertical tangents when $v_0 > 2$.
>
> From here, it is relatively simple to show the particle moves to an
> infinite distance when $v_0 > 2$. With the condition that $v_0 > 2$,
> $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is a continuous function that is always positive for
> all values $x$. Therefore, the integral of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is
> monotonically increasing, which implies that $x \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

---

The part I struggle with is showing the point oscillates about the origin if $v_0 < 2$:

> When $v_0 < 2$, $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is undefined for $x \in [\cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}) + 2\pi k, -\cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}) + 2\pi k]$, where $k$ is any integer number. At this part, it seemed natural
> to me to restrict the domain of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ to $(-\cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}), \cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}))$.
>
> While it's not possible to analytically obtain an expression for the
> integral of $\frac{dt}{dx}$, we can try to imagine what the graph of
> the integral of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ would look like. In the restricted
> domain of $(-\cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}), \cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}))$, the graph of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ looks similar to a
> parabola, which means that the graph of the integral of
> $\frac{dt}{dx}$ would look similar to a cubic curve with vertical
> tangents at $x = -\cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2}), \cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2})$. Thus, this line of thinking suggests that $x \to \cos^{-1} (\frac{2-v_0^2}{2})$ as $t \to \infty$, which is not the
> result I need.

Is there something obvious I am missing here, or have I made a careless mistake?

Comment: You get the periodicity of the "slow" solutions by examining the closeness of the given pendulum ODE to the ODE $\ddot x+x=0$ of the harmonic oscillator. Essentially, introduce some kind of polar coordinates and deduce that the angle always has only one direction. For some examples see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3401669/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3235466/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049326/115115.